# Make XSL refer to external text file?

Tags: file, xslt, external, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to reuse a text file in multiple XSL files, but am unsure what tag to use to reference the file's contents.

In other words, I want to copy the text out of a file, and dump it in a certain location inside my XSL file.

I'm using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you'll probably want to pass the contents of the text file as an `xsl:param` (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#variables).

If you were using XSLT 2.0, you could use `unparsed-text()`.